# caching using .htaccess - one image not caching weirdness

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, caching

I'm on a shared hosted linux server so I must use `.htaccess`. I'm busy working on compressing and caching things. I actually have two questions, but first here is how I have the cache setup in my .htaccess file.

```
ExpiresActive on
<FilesMatch "\.(bmp|png|ico|gff|jpg|jpeg|gif|gcf)$">
FileETag MTime Size
ExpiresDefault "now plus 60 minutes"
</FilesMatch>
```

**Question 1**, so this does cache those things with the exception of one PNG file.

Now most of my files are all lowercase as I'm on Linux but a few PNG files have slipped through with and upper case extension.

What's strange is that all of the PNG files cache except for one called `addon2.PNG`. At first I thought it was because of the case but I have checked and I have 3 other PNG files with uppercase extensions - which Google Page Speed says are cached. So any ideas or is Google Page Speed just B.S.?

**And question 2**, as I'm wary due to my hosts mess up with their Varnish issue I'm adding things to cache a little at a time and waiting to see if my stuff screws up. When I try to cache HTML files the login/logout features of my site—written in PHP—do not work.

You have to login and refresh or logout and refresh. I'm wondering is that because the page HTML is output via the PHP file? All my main pages are PHP and I only have a few actual html files. But I thought caching HTML would just do those files with htm & html extensions using the code below. But it's kinda like the server is trying to cache the html outputted by the PHP files. Am I out of my mind here?

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "now plus 60 minutes"
ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 60 minutes"
<FilesMatch "\.(css|bmp|png|ico|htm|gff|html|jpg|jpeg|gif|gcf)$">
FileETag MTime Size
ExpiresDefault "now plus 60 minutes"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Provide request and response headers for the image.

Comment: unfortunatley I do not have cmd line access so used sniffer
GET /images/addon2.PNG HTTP/1.1
Host: ksa-codesphere.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Referer: http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html
Connection: close

Receiving Header:
HTTP/1.1·200·OK(CR)(LF)
Date:·Mon,·06·Jan·2014·01:43:40·GMT(CR)(LF)
Server:·Apache/2(CR)(LF)
Last-Modified:·Sun,·05·Jan·2014·03:21:40·GMT(CR)(LF)
ETag:·"303a685-968b-4ef30a449a0ce"(CR)(LF)
Accept-Ranges:·bytes(CR)(LF)
Content-Length:·38539(CR)(LF)
Connection:·close(CR)(LF)
Content-Type:·image/png(CR)(LF)
(CR)(LF)

Comment: hmmmm I used another sniffer to check results and it says no-cache when I get that image

Comment: firefox request header when going directly to the image and not the page hmmm max-age=0 weird

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0Referer:https://www.ksa-codesphere.com/If-None-Match:"303a685-968b-4ef30a449a0ce"If-Modified-Since:Sun, 05 Jan 2014 03:21:40 GMTHost:www.ksa-codesphere.comDNT:1Connection:keep-aliveCache-Control:max-age=0Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflateAccept:image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5

ff response
Server:Apache/2Etag:"303a685-968b-4ef30a449a0ce"Date:Mon, 06 Jan 2014 01:53:54 GMTConnection:close

guess

Answer (score 0):

Your long explanation basically boils down to a PNG image is not being cached & HTML is not refreshing. It could be that the PNG image you say is having issues (`addon2.PNG`) is simply damaged. But the problem with your question is you have not provided any headers to show what the output is.

If you are using Linux, just go to the terminal and use `curl` to get headers.  For example, this is how I can get headers sent with the main `Google` image on their homepage:

```
curl -I https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png
```

And the output of that command is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Oct 2013 01:35:39 GMT
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2013 23:39:21 GMT
Expires: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 23:39:21 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
Content-Length: 14022
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Age: 1647616
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
```

So in your case just type in this command—remember to set it to the real path of the image—like so:

```
curl -I https://url/to/your/site/addon2.PNG
```

And compare the headers against something you know is caching as you wish it to.

Also, `ExpiresDefault` & `Cache-Control` can sometimes slightly conflict with each other. So check those two values to see what your host is setting versus what your `.htaccess` is setting.

And regarding this:

> So any ideas or is Google Page Speed just B.S.?

All of those page benchmarking tools have varying usefulness. In general for the specific issue you are facing, they are not B.S. but utterly useless. It’s like you are in a car with an oil leak & some automatic system in the car is telling you to change your oil. You don’t need to “change your oil” you need to find the leak & plug it up so the oil stays in!

So in your case the best bet is to using Unix tools like `curl` to check what the header output is & adjust/tweak until you get it right.

**EDIT** Also, please look over this pretty in-depth—and useful—[caching guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching).

Comment: yeah I'm not planning to do everything they say to do and really the one png file is not a big issue to me with a site that has thousands of imgs but it was a weird thing that would not get out of my head lol. the html thing however I'd really like to figure out the most

Comment: oh wanted to add that the few html files I do have and wanted to cache are not used by the login php files I use

Comment: Just in case anyone runs into a similiar issue with htm/html caching. the prob is that in my .htaccess file I have both of these lines

        ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 60 minutes"
        <FilesMatch "\.(css|bmp|png|ico|htm|gff|html|jpg|jpeg|gif|gcf)$">

so it is not looking at just the extension but also the file type and my php files return the type of text/html. So it is trying to cache the php which I don't want.

Thanks to those telling me to look at the http headers on the img it prompted me to look at the headers on my php files.

I would close this but can't answer myself yet